# Using pytest with paralelism and progressbar in modules, I got many `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` - Probably Solved

Tags: python, pytest, valueerror

I run into an issue, where multiple tests in project got failed on "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.". Issue was that I was unable to replicate it on my local machine as our CI pipeline running unittests were using parallelism and I used aditionally `--pdb` option for running the tests on local.

```py
.venv\lib\site-packages\progressbar\shortcuts.py:10: in progressbar
    for result in progressbar(iterator):
.venv\lib\site-packages\progressbar\bar.py:456: in __next__
    self.start()
.venv\lib\site-packages\progressbar\bar.py:657: in start
    self.update(self.min_value, force=True)
.venv\lib\site-packages\progressbar\bar.py:589: in update
    StdRedirectMixin.update(self, value=value)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <progressbar.bar.ProgressBar object at 0x...>, value = 0

    def update(self, value=None):
>       self.fd.write('\r' + ' ' * self.term_width + '\r')
E       ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

From this it is obvious it is in `progressbar` lib (I'm using `progressbar2 v=3.38` with python `3.9.7`).

My actual solution is adding fixture into root `conftest.py` and it seems working:

```py
# conftest.py
import progressbar
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse='True')
def setup_progressbar():
    progressbar.streams.wrap_stderr()
    progressbar.streams.wrap_stdout()
```

Genuinely I'm adding this question as I was unable to find this solution anywhere, so it may help someone, but also I'm not 100% sure it is the best/most clean one. And someone may have better approach (like adding the progressbar wraps into some hook or test collection?)

Does anyone have other approach handiling same issue?